# Visually updating the position of a game object controlled by an animator controller

Tags: unity, c#

I have a game object that is controlled by an animator controller. In order to activate the next animator state, the user is supposed to grab this game object, and then move it from `Point A` to `Point B`.

As a test, in said game object's `Update()` method, I added the following line:

```
this.transform.localPosition += Vector3.up;
```

When running the game, I can see that the y-coordinate of the game object's position increases every single frame, just as intended. However, **visually**, the game object's position is not changing at all -- it remains in the same place all the time.

What should I do to ensure that game object's position is also **visually** updated?

**EDIT:**

Here are the properties of the animator I am using:

[image]

**EDIT:**

If relevant, here is the skinned mesh renderer for said game object:

[image]

Comment: if the animator handles the position, then you won't be able to change it in the code

Comment: Although I don’t think it would appear to be changing in the inspector if that were the problem.